# Get the number of distinct powers

Tags: haskell

I have written a Haskell program that computes the number of different powers in a list.

The function dist accepts 2 integers m n. The program computes the length of the list which contains all the numbers a^b  where 2<=a<=m and 2<=b<=n ; the number a^b is added only once in the list

Example

```
dist 5 5

-- 2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5,3^2,3^3 .....5^4,5^5 --
```

There are only 15 different values 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 243, 256, 625, 1024, 3125 so the answer will be 15.

Are there any improvements to my code that can be made in order to make it faster?Or maybe another approach that someone could suggest?

```
import Data.List

dist :: Int -> Int -> Int
dist m n =  length (nub (concat [x | a<-[2..m], let x = listpower a n] ))


listpower::Int->Int->[Int]
listpower a n = take (n-1) (powers a)


powers::Int->[Int]
powers a = [a^b| b<-[2..]]
```

Comment: `nub` is usually not the preferred way to do a uniqueness filter, since it does not work very efficient. You can use a *hash set*.

Comment: if you're just interested in the length, you can have a smarter algorithm to detect collisions and reduce the length. Note that only powers of square numbers can be a duplicate of a double power of the base number, here 4^2 and 2^4.  However, processing is cheap, analysis is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

The `Applicative` instance for lists makes this trivial.

```
dist m n = length . nub $ (^) <$> [2..m] <*> [2..n]
```

`(^) <$> [2..m]` results in a list of functions `fs = [(2^), (3^), ..., (m^)]`. `fs <*> [2..n]` then applies each of those functions to each value in `[2..n]`.

There is also a trivial list comprehension, as

```
f <$> xs <*> ys == [f x y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

.

Comment: I think for efficiency, instead of lists, it would be a better idea to use [`Data.Set.Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Monad.html) type with applicative to eliminate `nub`.

Comment: True; I completely missed the request to make it faster. I was only suggesting how to reduce a set of three separate functions to a simple expression using standard abstractions.